# How to establish database connection(MS SQL Server) for Rest Assured in the Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, rest-assured

I am automating APIs using Rest-Assured. My requirement is to connect to a Microsoft SQL server DB and compare the API response with the database table values.

I have created a Maven project and using TestNG

I am using IntelliJ IDEA tool for automation

Please help me with a sample project or code to establish the connection in Rest-Assured

Comment: There are 2 different things. You can't connect DB with Rest-Assured.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said previously, there is no way to connect Rest-Assured with DB, since Rest-Assured is an API client.
For connecting a DB in Java code try to use either Hibernate or JDBC.
I'd recommend the 1st option (Hibernate), because JDBC is quite legacy.

Hibernate tutorial from Google search - [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-hello-world-application/)

JDBC tutorial from Google search - [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm)

Comment: Can you please share a sample project or code to establish the DB connection with Hiberate or JDBC and integrate it with REST-Assured ?

Comment: @HelenaSteffy see my updated answer